# Delete Google Analytics cookie in AMP version

Tags: google-analytics, amp, gdpr

I'm developing a new AMP site. It's very simple and I just want to know visits/pageviews in Google Analytics.

Because of the European GDPR law, instead of notifying the users about the cookie, I just want to delete it and grab the metrics I need. My problem is that I can't execute external JavaScript to delete the cookie if I want to validate the AMP site.

Any ideas how could I delete the AMP Analytics cookie?